# taskdef A class needed by class com.android.ant.GetUiTargetTask cannot be found: com/android/utils/ILogger

Tags: android, android-studio, ant

After I update Android Studio to version 2.3, When I make my project I got this error

> /Users/xxx/Work/yyy/build.xml:96: taskdef A class needed by class com.android.ant.GetUiTargetTask cannot be found: com/android/utils/ILogger
>           using the classloader AntClassLoader[/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/ant-tasks.jar:/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/kxml2-2.3.0.jar:/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar:/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/httpmime-4.1.jar:/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/httpcore-4.1.jar:/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar]
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.addDefinition(Definer.java:612)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.loadProperties(Definer.java:408)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:264)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:180)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:93)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:832)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:287)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:113)
>           Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/ILogger
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.addDefinition(Definer.java:579)
>       ... 16 more
>           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.utils.ILogger
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1384)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1333)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1088)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 19 more

And this is the code line in build.xml that mentioned

```
<taskdef resource="anttasks.properties" classpathref="android.antlibs" />
<property name="exe" value="" />
<property name="bat" value="" />
```

Before update I never see this error. How I fix this error.

Comment: Looks like they've removed the ant-tasks.jar from the latest Android SDK which is probably causing your error?

Comment: I've copied ant-tasks.jar from another computer to latest Android SDK and I see this error

Comment: Did you copy all those dependant jar's as well?

Comment: I think I did it

Answer (score 4):

You need to copy the mentioned files from tools that still have them, like windows version:

```
ant/*
lib/ant-tasks.jar
lib/common.jar
lib/sdklib.jar
lib/guava-17.0.jar
lib/manifest-merger.jar
```

Comment: It would improve the quality of your answer if you could include an explanation of what fault was occurring and how your suggested solution solves the problem.

Comment: This was a life saver. I am a mac user and was facing this issue. Got these jars form a friend and it worked!

Comment: I had to also add gson-2.2.4.jar

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded and installed android `tools` version `25.2.3` that still have `ant` that fix this problem

Comment: I have android tools  version 26.0.1 installed But I don't have ant . Then how to fix this problem ?